# Open generated pdf in Windows8

Tags: cordova, windows-8, winjs, jspdf

I am using the javascript library jsPDF to generate a pdf. I need to open the generated pdf in Windows 8. using window.open does not work. I tried saving the file and opening with no success.

How can I open the pdf?

[UDPATE]

I am trying to save it using writeBufferAsync like this:

```
        var data = pdf.output('arraybuffer');

        Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeBufferAsync(file, data).done(function () {
            // Let Windows know that we're finished changing the file so the other app can update the remote version of the file.
            // Completing updates may require Windows to ask for user input.
            Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.completeUpdatesAsync(file).done(function (updateStatus) {
                if (updateStatus === Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus.complete) {
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + file.name + " was saved.", "sample", "status");
                } else {
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + file.name + " couldn't be saved.", "sample", "status");
                }
            });
        });
```

But I keep getting exception that I writeBufferAsync is expecting number array. Type of data is ArrayBuffer.

[Update 2]

I tried the following, bug images don's show:

```
var data = pdf.output();

Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, data).done(function () {
    // Let Windows know that we're finished changing the file so the other app can update the remote version of the file.
    // Completing updates may require Windows to ask for user input.
    Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.completeUpdatesAsync(file).done(function (updateStatus) {
        if (updateStatus === Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus.complete) {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + file.name + " was saved.", "sample", "status");
        } else {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + file.name + " couldn't be saved.", "sample", "status");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you get an error when using `window.open`?

Comment: No error or exception when I use window.open. I tried with a data string but it prompts for an app to open schema data:

Answer (score 1):

Write the PDF to the file system and use window.open(fileURL, '_blank') to open it. That's all you should have to do. How did you try to open it and what happened when you did?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where your function pdf.output() is coming from...  did you write it yourself?

According to the API ([https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L355)), you should have a reference to your document and then just call:

```
document.getData()
```

this returns a promise which you can then use in the writeTextAsync function.  The API says it returns a typed array.  I would assume it is the same type as what you can load a PDF document with... an array of uint8.  If you need to convert it, do it then.

If promises are the problem, then it should go something like this:

```
document.getData().done(function(arg) {
//do something with the results here...
}
```

Comment: ahhh... ok, sorry.  Wow, that's confusing

Answer (score 0):

The best way to open or launch a file is with [Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync.aspx). You give it the StorageFile object and it does the rest, opening whatever app the user has assigned to PDFs, or prompting the user to select one.

If you need to render the PDF directly in your app, then use [Windows.Data.Pdf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.pdf.aspx) API. Refer to the [PDF viewer sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PDF-viewer-sample-85a4bb30).

P.S. If you're writing the file to the local file system in a place that you know isn't tied to cloud storage, then you don't need to use the CachedFileUpdater. That is, if you're writing to your local appdata or temp appdata, you can omit that call.